# ListUtils Subtract is not working as expected

Tags: java, collections

I have couple of list of objects `List<test> listA` and `List<test> listB`. I need to subtract `listA` and `listB` and get the list of objects which don't match in listA and listB. In case if both lists have the same object I should not get any values back. I tried using `ListUtils.Subtract` but unfortunately, I'm not getting the correct result. Please see my sample code below:

```
public class test {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
    public test(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
    
List<test> listA = new  ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(new test("sam", "rik")));
List<test> listB = new ArrayList<>();
listB.add(new test("sam", "rik"));
listB.add(new test("nick", "wilson"));
    
List<test> reslt = ListUtils.subtract(listB, listA); // I need to  get only nick and wilson object here
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't overridden `.equals()` method for `test` class. `ListUtils.subtract()` uses `equals()` method to determine the items to delete.

Override `.equals()` in `test` class, so that two `test` instances with identical fields value will be counted as equal.

Example of `.equals()` implementation for identical fields value

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    
    if (this == o)return true;// self check
    if (o == null) return false; // null check
    if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false; // type check and cast
    Test test = (Test) o;
    // field comparison
    return Objects.equals(firstName, test.firstName)
            && Objects.equals(lastName, test.lastName);
}
```